SCP Transfer Interrupted with 'Broken Pipe Client Disconnect' Error - Self-Developed Modems"
I'm encountering an issue with SCP transfers between two systems connected via self-developed modems. When attempting to transfer a large file(around 7GB), the transfer starts successfully but eventually sometimes halts with an error message stating "Broken Pipe Client Disconnect."
Upon inspecting the network traffic using Wireshark, I observed a pattern of ACK,RST packet followed by RST packets, ultimately leading to the termination of the connection.
I've tried troubleshooting by checking for any network issues, ensuring proper configuration of the modems, and examining the SCP settings, but the problem persists.
Can someone provide insights into what might be causing this issue and suggest potential solutions to resolve it? Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Wireshark log screenshot attached
Thank you.
